# How to count teams and members

Tags: sql, tree, sas, data-mining, hierarchical-data

I have a table like this:

|personid| supervisorid| date_in|

each person can have only a supervisor (that is a person himself and can have a supervisor).

I'd like to compute:

- the number of "teams" that should be the number of person without a supervisor that have at least two persons under them;
- the number of members of persons for each teams;
- the number of "active teams" defined as teams with a new person added less than X days ago.

Thanks in advance for your help.

DATA:

```
personid|supervisorid   |datein
--------+---------------+----------
001     |NA             |01/09/2020
002     |001            |01/09/2020
003     |001            |01/09/2020
004     |003            |01/09/2020
005     |003            |01/09/2020
006     |003            |01/09/2020
007     |003            |01/09/2020
008     |NA             |01/09/2020
009     |008            |01/01/1990
010     |008            |01/01/1990
011     |NA             |01/01/1990
012     |011            |01/01/1990
```

Result:

```
-number of teams:2
-members per team:

supervisor team|num_members
---------------+-----------
001            |7
008            |3

-active teams in the last 30 days: 1 (supervisorid=001)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: shouldn't `personid = 011` also have a team, consisting of 1 member?

Comment: teams are group of persons with a supervisor that has >= 2 persons under him as stated

Comment: You should also show what you tried to solve this question. Why the restriction to SQL?

Comment: This approach will work https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-macro-for-finding-all-paths-in-a-directed-graph-network/ta-p/221568

Answer (score 0):

if you you have sas, you can use proc sql
*the number of "teams" that should be the number of person without a supervisor that have at least two persons under them;

```
select count(distinct a.personid) as teams 
from (select personid from yourtable where supervisorid='NA' group by 1) a   
inner join (select supervisorid , count(distinct personid) as num_members from yourtable group by 1) b on a.personid=b.supervisorid ;
```

*the number of members of persons for each teams;

```
select a.person_id as supervisorteam,b.num_members
from(select personid from yourtable where supervisorid='NA' group by 1) a   
inner join (select supervisorid , count(distinct personid) as num_members from yourtable group by 1 having num_members>1) b on a.personid=b.supervisorid ;
```

*the number of "active teams" defined as teams with a new person added less than X days ago

```
select count(distinct a.personid) as active
from (select personid from yourtable where supervisorid='NA' and datein<Xdaysago group by 1) a   
inner join (select supervisorid , count(distinct personid) as num_members from yourtable group by 1 having num_members>1) b on a.personid=b.supervisorid ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it's not quite right.
The team can be "multi-level" and for this reason the supervisor 001's team has 7 members since: level 0 : 001;
                          level 1 : 002, 003
                          level 2 : 004, 005, 006, 007 (since all of them are supervised by 003).
From the code you posted it would have only 3 persons